# Get 5 random posts within current category in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I want to only get 5 posts within current category by random using the following code.

```
// Get all posts within current category, but exclude current post
        $category_posts = new WP_Query( array(
            'cat'          => $categories[0]->term_id,
            'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() ),
        ) );
```

How do you apply the '5 posts' limit and 'order by random' to the above code?

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Pagination_Parameters, https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

Answer (score 0):

as for me, I would use get_posts(), but these arguments should work in your case as well:

```
<?php $args = array(
'numberposts'      => 5,
'category'         => $categories[0]->term_id,
'orderby'          => 'rand',
'exclude'          => array( get_the_ID() ),
'post_type'        => 'post',
'post_status'      => 'publish',
'suppress_filters' => true 
);

$posts_array = get_posts( $args ); ?>
```

More about this here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code.

```
           // Get all posts within current category, but exclude current post
        $category_posts = new WP_Query( array(
        'orderby'        => 'rand',
        'cat'          => $categories[0]->term_id,
        'post__not_in' => array( get_the_ID() ),
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        ) );
```